# Mountpoint permissions messed up after user mount

Tags: permissions, debian, mount, file-permissions, debian-squeeze

On a freshly installed Debian squeeze amd64,

```
$ ls /media -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 13 12:13 usb0
```

But after mounting,

```
$ mount /dev/sdb1 
$ ls /media -l
drwx------ 1 root root 4096 Jun 12 18:11 usb0
```

which makes the mount-point unusable for the user who mounted it.

### fstab entry

```
/dev/sdb1       /media/usb0     auto    defaults,rw,user,noauto  0       0
```

Is there a fix that enables the user to make the mount-point easily accessible to the user with the mount command itself (instead of a separate `sudo chmod` command)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the `umask` mount options:

```
/dev/sdb1       /media/usb0     auto    defaults,rw,user,noauto,umask=022  0       0
```

Comment: `umask` option alone did the trick